# JQuery :contains() does not select the text if it is surrounded by tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this JQuery script:

```
$('#searchinput').keypress(function() {
  $('#realadstable tr').show().not(':contains(' + this.value + ')').hide();
});
```

Basically it filters the rows of the table to show only those that contain the text typed in input field #searchinput.

The problem is that this script does not see the text surrounded by other tags (like bold text) so it can hide the row that contains necessary text only because it is surrounded by bold tags.

How do I fix that?
thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `filter` function:

```
$('#searchinput').keypress(function() {
    $('#realadstable tr').show().filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().indexOf(this.value) !== -1;
    }).hide();
});
```

Comment: @SerhyiVynohradov: That doesn't really help me help you, what I wrote should work unless you are leaving something else out. It is case sensitive, so you would have to do text().toLowerCase() and this.value.toLowerCase() if you wanted it to not be.